# Writing a Editor like Notepad++

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I think this is a project in future though not very near (I have other project I'm working on) but as I always do, I love to ask questions and get clear view of what is facing me and may be slowly learn some useful things. I am a fan of netbeans (Because so far is the only IDE that can meet my need) for PHP coding but it is very resource hunger. MAC people are blessed with Nice IDEs like Coda, TextMate et al. I though in future I would code an IDE and if thing goes wel I may well sell it :)

Now My question is, what one needs to know to code such an editor?
I know how to make GUI and events interaction in wxWidgets and I know there is wxSTC for making editors but I lack general knowledge of what is needed to make full fledged PHP editor (adding there by Javascript/Html support).

Google didn't help much, may be I'm using wrong keyewords
Thanks for direction and/or help

Comment: I would consider buying one instead. 300.00 for Zend Studio is not that much. If not there are eclipse plugins that might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with wxSTC. [The Wiki docs](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxStyledTextCtrl) were helpful to start with, then [scintilla docs](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html) and finally [wxSTC Docs at yellowbrain](http://www.yellowbrain.com/stc/) are wonderful!